# How to use CSS to limit Table Header to 2 lines

Tags: html, css

Limiting to a line would be simple using `white-space:nowrap` but I have a specific problem where I would like to force my header text to fit in a specific width.

I had success adding individual style on the  element to force them to the specific 2 lines I want but it does not seem like a long term solution.

e.g.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                <th style="min-width: 90px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Another way I tried was to include break points in the text itself but I also don't want to go through the multiple files to do so.

```
<th>Lorem ipsum <br /> dolor sit amet</th>
```

I have also tried adding a external style sheet to force the min-width of all to a value but this causes huge gaps in-between the table headers.

Would like to know if there's a better method to do this.

Comment: You used min-width, not max-width.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `max-width` property on all the headers. The amount of headers multiplied by the chosen width will amount to the maximum width of the table.

Here's an example of `max-width` which with 6 headers as per your example amounts to a maximum of `300px`.

```
thead th {
    max-width: 50px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the table overflow on the horizontal so I cannot use max-width as it causes it to bunch all the text together

Comment: Then unhide the overflow? I dont understand how you expect to change the size of a table without having to manage overflow. You could change the fontsize but i doubt that's what you're looking for. Either way your question is very broad and you have not specified what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `line-clamp` property.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span class='table-header-limit'>Lorem ipsum</span></th>
                <th><span class='table-header-limit'>Lorem ipsum</span></th>
                <th><span class='table-header-limit'>Lorem ipsum</span></th>
                <th><span class='table-header-limit'>Lorem ipsum</span></th>
                <th><span class='table-header-limit'>Lorem ipsum</span></th>
                <th><span class='table-header-limit'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.table-header-limit {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Output
[image]